# Codeigniter redirect domain to subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I am attempting to redirect example.com to subdomain.example.com using codeigniters (3) redirect($domain).  But what I end up with in the browser address bar is base_url/$domain when all I want is $domain.

The controller is set to look at the url and determine if the user has visited without a subdomain.  If that is the case they are redirected to a view that asks them where they are from.  This data is then passed to the same controller with a $_POST telling it where they are from.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
    $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);

    $subdomain = $subdomain_arr[0];
    if ($_POST != NULL)
    {
        $post = $_POST; 
        $subnames = $this->sendy->subName($post);//returns subdomain 

        foreach ($subnames as $subname) 
        {
            $sub = $subname->subdomain;
        }

        $subdomain = $sub;
        $period = ".";
        $domain = $subdomain.$period.$subdomain_arr[0].$period.$subdomain_arr[1];
        redirect($domain, 'auto');
    }
```

There are thousands of possible subdomains.  I just need codeigniter to prepend the subdomain and reload the page so that the url appears in the browser address bar as subdomain.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Derp! I added http:// to the $domain var and now it works as expected. Sorry for the asshatery.

```
$subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2);

    $subdomain = $subdomain_arr[0];
    if ($_POST != NULL)
    {
        $post = $_POST; //this is the library name
        $subnames = $this->sendy->subName($post);

        foreach ($subnames as $subname) 
        {
            $sub = $subname->subdomain;
        }

        $subdomain = $sub;
        $period = ".";
        $http = "http://";
        $domain = $http.$subdomain.$period.$subdomain_arr[0].$period.$subdomain_arr[1];
        redirect($domain, 'location');
    }
```

With the addition of the $http now the redirect works properly.